# GKShuffledDistribution - using upperbound doesn't exhaust all possible values?

Tags: swift, gameplay-kit

I'm trying to use GKShuffledDistribution in one of my apps but the nextInt(upperBound:) method doesn't work the same as the nextInt method in that it doesn't exhaust all possible values. To demonstrate, open a playground and do this:

```
import GameplayKit
let shuffled = GKShuffledDistribution.init(lowestValue: 0, highestValue: 100)

for _ in 0...25{
    shuffled.nextInt(upperBound: 100)
}
```

I got 2 duplicates using this method. If I replaced it with:

```
shuffled.nextInt()
```

I don't get any duplicates. Is this how nextInt(upperBound:) supposed to work? If it is, can some one point me to documentation explaining this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`upperBound` is provided to let you ask for a random value between your `lowestValue` and a new (temporary) `highestValue` that's less than the `highestValue` you've set when creating your `GKShuffledDistribution` instance.

Oops. That's mealy mouthed.

**Let me try this more pictorially.**

IF you normally want a random number between 0 and 20, but sometimes you want one that's only between 0 and 10, from this same shuffle, then you can set upperBound to 10 and a number will be "pulled out" that's between 0 and 10, of the numbers left in your current shuffle cycle.

*Well... at least I think that's how it's supposed to work.*

Theoretically, when you set the `upperBound` to 100, as in your example, the `highestValue` should be the determinant of activity, [**since the docs suggest:**](https://developer.apple.com/reference/gameplaykit/gkrandomdistribution/1495638-nextint)

> The actual upper bound on numbers generated by this method is the
>   lesser of the highestValue property and the upperBound parameter.

Comment: Thanks for helping me trying to understand this. So when I used `upperBound` in the for loop, it was temporarily changing that value to 100 every time I went through the for loop, causing the duplicates that I was seeing. Is this correct?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how it works when you use the same number as your `highestValue`. Or how many numbers you're pumping out before you see repeats. There might be a bug. GameplayKit is used by about 3 people, so it wouldn't have been thoroughly tested.

Comment: So I tested this in the playground by setting upperBound to 5 and the for loop 0...3. The results I got were "4, 0, 1, 1", confirming your original answer that upperBound becomes the temporary "highestValue" in the for loop. Once the loop iterates, no memory of the temporary "highestValue" is retained, thus I got a repeated value before all possible values were selected. Your answer help me understand this parameter when Apple failed to do so. Thank you.